# Cannot change brightness of Dell backlit keyboard

Tags: keyboard, dell-inspiron, backlight

I'm using a Dell Inspiron 5547 laptop --and the usual way to change the brightness of the backlit keyboard is to use the F10 key. I recently replaced my laptop keyboard, and ever since I'm not able to change the brightness of the backlit keyboard, or switch the backlighting off.

I've tried going to Windows Mobility Center but there's no option there at all for backlight brightness (just the basic ones such as monitor brigthness, volume, battery and sync etc. are present).

I can't really say for sure if the issue came up only after I replaced the keyboard because I can't remember the last time I tried to adjust the backlight brightness on my previous keyboard.

Comment: Maybe you just replaced the `led sheet stuff` beneath it while replacing the keyboard and Now there are no led lights anymore : (